# Can I write $\sum_{n=1}\frac{n}{2^n}$ as sum of odd and even?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was wonder why I can't write : $\sum_{n=1}\frac{n}{2^n}$, as:

$\sum_{n=1}\frac{n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}\frac{2n}{2^n}+\sum_{n=1}\frac{(2n-1)}{2^n}$

It seems logic to say that the sum of the odd and even for $n$ will be the sum of the original,but I got :

$\sum_{n=1}\frac{n}{2^n}=2\sum_{n=1}\frac{n}{2^n}+2\sum_{n=1}\frac{(n)}{2^n}-\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{2^n}$

And that's not give me $S=2$.

- all are infinite sums.

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to replace $n \to 2n$ and $n \to 2n-1$ in the denominator of the respective sums. Then they are equivalent.

Comment: I didn't  forget,  I just put them out of the sigma.

Comment: No idea what you mean by that comment, "I just put them out of the sigma." How?

Comment: I mean by my step.  From the first equation,  to the second one, when I wrote as $2\sum....$

Comment: Try writing out a few terms.

Comment: Dona, @Gregory was talking about the first equation you wrote. That first equation is incorrect, because of what Gregory pointed out.

Comment: I can't see why,  if I put $n=1$ I get $2/2^2$ in the even sigma term.  That will give me all the even in the denominator. And in the second term (right side of first equation)  I'll get $1/2^2$  and so on will give me all the odd in the denominator. So together I'll get the original sum .

Comment: Oh I see now.  Sorry my English isn't well I thought you mean about the numerator.

Comment: You are in effect assuming $\sum a_nb_n=(\sum a_n)(\sum b_n)$. This is not true, when you multiply out the two sums on the right, there are a lot of "mixed" terms.

Comment: Where did I assume that? I just took the $2$ before the sum.

Comment: @Dona, why are you separating them? I don't believe that makes it any easier to solve...

Comment: Yes,  you are right.  I tried to solve it by sums in terms of sigma.  But I guess it isn't that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\sum_{n=1}\frac{n}{2^n}~=~\sum_{n=1}\frac{2n}{2^n}~+~\sum_{n=1}\frac{2n-1}{2^n}$$

I assume what you **actually** meant to write is

> $$\sum_{n=1}\frac{n}{2^n}~=~\sum_{n=1}\frac{2n}{2^{\color{blue}{2n}}}~+~\sum_{n=1}\frac{2n-1}{2^{\color{blue}{2n-1}}}$$

Comment: Yes,  thank you.  I guess I cant solve this equation in that way..

Comment: @Dona: Probably not, but you can deduce the value of $~\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n}{4^n}~$

Comment: Can you elaborate about that?

Comment: @Dona: Well, it would follow that $S_2=2S_4+2\bigg(2S_4-\dfrac1{4-1}\bigg),~$ where $S_2=2$.